# Password autofill / suggestion on iOS using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, keychain

Is it possible to get the password suggestion and credential autofill (on QuickType bar) working for an app that uses firebase for auth/backend services?

The examples I've seen suggest that you need your own dedicated backend with a website in order to do this.

Comment: A QuickType bar and Firebase are two unrelated technologies. The QuickType bar is a UI element and Firebase is where the app data is stored. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow) for password autofill for more reading.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant when the password suggestion appears just above the keyboard on a login screen for example

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found that the way the secure password suggestion and autofill works is that it uses Associated domains. In the case of firebase this can be done using dynamic links and then uploading an app association file to the server, with this address referenced in the associated domains capability on Xcode.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive